# Rmagic error : R has no attribute png

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, rpy2

I just installed rpy2 through conda-forge and when I use it in a jupyter notebook I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py in __getattribute__(self, attr)
    325         try:
--> 326             return self.__getitem__(attr)
    327         except LookupError as le:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py in __getitem__(self, item)
    330     def __getitem__(self, item):
--> 331         res = _globalenv.get(item)
    332         res = conversion.ri2py(res)

LookupError: 'png' not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c9dc5af3c1ce> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('R', '2+2')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2129                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2130             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2131                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2132             return result
   2133 

<decorator-gen-130> in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\ipython\rmagic.py in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)
    685                     ro.r.assign(input, val)
    686 
--> 687         tmpd = self.setup_graphics(args)
    688 
    689         text_output = ''

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\ipython\rmagic.py in setup_graphics(self, args)
    422             if self.device == 'png':
    423                 # Note: that %% is to pass into R for interpolation there
--> 424                 ro.r.png("%s/Rplots%%03d.png" % tmpd_fix_slashes,
    425                         **argdict)
    426             elif self.device == 'svg':

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py in __getattribute__(self, attr)
    326             return self.__getitem__(attr)
    327         except LookupError as le:
--> 328             raise AttributeError(orig_ae)
    329 
    330     def __getitem__(self, item):

AttributeError: 'R' object has no attribute 'png'
```

I tried to reinstall rpy2 and looked on the internet but I couldn't find any solution do anyone ever had this issue?

I am running windows 7 and in my Jupyter I loaded the package with

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

R on your system was likely compiled without PNG support. This might be rather uncommon nowadays, but I guess the R magic should catch it.

Now tracked in https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/476/catching-missing-png-capabilities-in-r